# Symfony 3.4 overwrites env variables with the ones from parameters.yml

Tags: php, symfony

I have the following setup which appeared to work for some time: environment variables like TEST=1 and defined defaults in parameters.yml, according to the config:

```
parameters:
    env(TEST): 2
```

When I go to console and output the container params, it's always the value from parameters.yaml:

```
bin/console debug:container --parameters | grep env
env(TEST) 2
```

I also tried doing exactly as it's said in the docs:

```
TEST: "%env(TEST)%"
env(TEST): 2
```

Now when I dump the parameters, I have both of them:

```
bin/console debug:container --parameters | grep env
TEST %env(TEST)%
env(TEST) 2
```

To be more precise: I use docker setup, and printenv inside a container gives me my TEST=1 shown.

Can someone explain me what happens/happened here? It's been working for some time, and then, probably after some major update, got broken.

I tried debugging it and got to a very strange place in Symfony sources: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php#L1416

At that very line, there's a value "2" being passed, and it doesn't meet the conditions and gets returned.

Comment: I'm sorry for so basic a question, but you're running both `printenv` and `bin/console ...` from inside the same docker container, right? (Just to eliminate the possibility up front!)

Comment: Also - you updated from version what to what? (3.2 to 3.4?)

Comment: @CameronHurd yes, that's right, everything is being run from inside the same docker container. About the version, it started from 3.4, and the update was minor - from some 3.4.3 to 3.4.14 or so. Generally there should be no breaking changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like everything works correctly - it's just the parameter debug output that confused me.